# Is it a secret minimal size(width/height) of em DIV in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome

I have a div with width & height in em. It regulated by the font-size of its parent div.

When I set the font-size of the parent less than 6px it doesn't change. Before and in Firefox it works as it should be.

MacOS, Chrome Version 74.0.3729.131 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Here is an example, it will be the same size, even it is 6px and 2px:

```html
<div style="font-size: 6px">
  <div style="height: 10.36em; width: 10.2em; border: 1px solid red;"><span style="font-size:2em">text</span></div>
</div>
```

```html
<div style="font-size: 2px">
  <div style="height: 10.36em; width: 10.2em; border: 1px solid red;"><span style="font-size:2em">text</span></div>
</div>
```

That's how I see it:
[image]

Why and how to fix it?

P.S. so it looks like it is a bug, I reported it here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=963414

Comment: It looks fine to me

Comment: @Turnip I have Chrome Version 74.0.3729.131 MacOS

Comment: It looks fine to me. If you're issue is persisting, have you ever tried to use webkit CSS ? https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/WebKit_Extensions

Comment: @Eugene I'm on the same version. So the two example in your question both produce the same result?

Comment: @Turnip yes, I added the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

It's because Chrome has “minimum font size” setting which is 6px by default.
It is better to write about this Chrome setting.

Comment: If this is the really the case, why am I able to use font sizes of smaller than 6px without issue?

Comment: Google chrome comes with minimum 6px for now(V67). Check your browser config, it has a section about minimum font size, probably it’s something like 0, so if you set to 6px, numbers less than that will be ignored. Go to menu -> settings -> search for and goto “Customize fonts” -> adjust the minimum font size

Comment: Interesting, but look, I added a text inside, it will shrink with font-size of the parent less 6px. But div itself won't...

Comment: I think it is better to write about this Chrome setting and font size of your "div" change to 6px